# login faild when autorize dovecot from pam

Tags: ubuntu, authentication, dovecot, pam

I installed dovecot 2.0.13 with postfix in ubuntu server 11.10 , after installation I can send e-mail with the `mail` command and dovecot works when I test it with `telnet`

I then installed roundcube on it , and the installation passed all tests.

I want to authorize dovecot with system users through pam so I  wrote in my dovecot.conf :

```
passwd pam {

 args = *

}
```

and in pam.d/dovecot I wrote :

```
auth    required        pam_unix.so nullok
account required        pam_unix.so
```

then when I reload dovecot and try to login it still fails.

So how can I solve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `args = dovecot` in dovecot.conf